# Quick Ramp-up for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am an experienced .NET applications developer.  All of my development experience has been with desktop apps with WinForms/WPF.

The last time I worked with ASP was back in 1998.  A lot has changed with ASP.NET, and I realize this.  I am wondering what is the best resource for ramping up **quickly** with ASP.NET and WebForms (not MVC).  Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always recommend this site:

[ASP .NET Learn](http://www.asp.net/learn/)

It's the official ASP .NET site, there you'll find really good videos that will help you to get up developing quickly in ASP .NET

Answer (score 2):

The [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx?ppud=4), must you know, padawan, if seek to master the web, you do

Comment: Shameless self promo: http://john-sheehan.com/blog/index.php/net-cheat-sheets/ for a Life Cycle cheat sheet

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find that the best way is to start digging in, find either an existing project to enhance or start out building something.  The best way for me anyway is to have a problem to solve, by doing this it makes life a lot easier.  At least that is the way I learn new technologies.

There are many good reference/tutorial sites out there as well that could help you out a lot, such as 4GuysFromRolla.com.

Answer (score 1):

- [HTML/CSS Tutorials](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/)
- [ASP.NET Quickstart Tutorial](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/Default.aspx)
- [Nice series of videos](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/26/439088.aspx)
- [.NET 3.5 Enhancements Training Kit RTM](http://lostintangent.com/2008/08/11/net-35-enhancements-training-kit-rtm/)

ASP.NET Learn already mentioned.